# Merge function with several key repetitions on the "right-crossing" data frame

Tags: r, matching

sorry for the noob question but I really don't know where to search for the procedure I must do. My problem is that I need to find all matches of one column into another database to get the value of another column. Some sort of a merge but in this case I have several repeated values in the right database, so I need to get all matches.

To be clearer: suppose that I have this kind of data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(CustomerId=c("a","b","c","h"))

   CustomerId
1          a
2          b
3          c
4          h
```

and my other dataframe would be something like:

```
df2<-data.frame(CustomerID=c("a","b","b","b","a","d","c"),code=c(1,2,2,3,2,4,4))
  CustomerID code
1          a    1
2          b    2
3          b    2
4          b    3
5          a    2
6          d    4
7          c    4
```

I need to "merge" this two dataframes so that I can get all the codes for every one of the customersIDs. I would need something like this:

```
  CustomerId codes
1          a   1,2
2          b   2,3
3          c     4
4          h    NA
```

The problems I found so far are:

- I have my key repeated several times on the crossing dataframe
- I could use a loop but my database is so large that I need to avoid inefficiencies
- the amount of times that the customerId can be repeated on the second dataframe is variable
- It could happen that one of the customerId repeat several times but only have one code so I would need only one code, not all of them
- If a CustomerId is not found on the second database I would need a NA value

Thanks for your help guys, hope you can help me

Comment: I think this should work  `left_join(df,unique(df2)) %>% group_by(CustomerId) %>% summarise(codes=paste(code, collapse = ","))` but how big is your data? BTW, it works if you have exactly the same names on both dataframes, R is case sensitive (otherwise specify the by clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

#Convert data.frames to data.tables
dt = data.table(df,key="CustomerId")
dt2 = data.table(df2, key ="CustomerID")

#rename to account for case sensitivity 
setnames(dt2,"CustomerID","CustomerId")

#merge files retaining all values even those that has no matching key
dt3 = merge(dt,dt2,all=T)

#list unique codes split by "CustomerId"
dt3[,list(code=list(unique(code))),by="CustomerId"]
```

If one feels uncomfortable working with data.tables beyond this point any `data.table` object might easily be reconverted to `data.frame`as simple as: `df = data.frame(dt)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another quick solution using `data.table` binary join

```
library(data.table)
Res <- setDT(df2)[, .(codes = toString(unique(code))), key = CustomerID]
Res[df]
#    CustomerID codes
# 1:          a  1, 2
# 2:          b  2, 3
# 3:          c     4
# 4:          h    NA
```

Comment: Nice use of `toString`